# Solving Error when instantiating an object of a compiled class in JSP page

Tags: jar

Please I need your Help all Java gurus in the forum, i have a problem with a jar file am importing to my jsp file when i define an object of the imported class PassBuilder.java (which is a class in the passhide jar file imported)as "PassBuider passer;" i get no error but once i instantiate the class object i get a "page cannot be displayed error". Please what can i do to solve this????Below is a sample of the code:

```
<%@ page import= "passhide.*"%>

<%
String userID = "owo123";
PassBuilder passer;//no error
passer = new PassBuiler().getPass(userID);//throws page cannot be displayed
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I later found the solution to this, the cause was actually me running a jar file compiled with jdk 1.7 on a jdk 1.6 environment. so I simply had to recompile with a jdk 1.6, and holla the error was gone.